# Reading a file 16 bytes at a time issue

Tags: c#

I'm in the process of writing a C# serial interface for FPGA project I'm working on and I've hit an issue. I need to read a file 16 bytes at a time, send the 16 bytes and then upon correct receipt send the next 16 bytes etc..

During debug though I am getting errors with reading the file however:

*(Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection.)

The file is about 1200 bytes and the error is occurring on the second time the program tries to read 16 bytes ( i.e. bytes 16-31 of the file).

Any Ideas? Is using an offset with a count the wrong way to do this? I am extremely inexperienced with high level programming so you help would be much appreciated

Regards,
Michael

```
        ///////////////////// Get file data ///////////////////
        else if (fileDataSent == false)
        {
            FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(tbFileToSend.Text);
            try
            {
                byte[] readBytes = new byte[16];
                fs.Read(readBytes, nextReadOffset, 16);
                fs.Close();
                for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++)
                {
                    sendData[j + 3] = readBytes[j];
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                fs.Close();
            }
            nextReadOffset = nextReadOffset + 16;
            dataBytesSent = dataBytesSent + 16;
            sendData[0] = Convert.ToByte("10000001", 2);
            sendData[1] = ByteID;
            sendData[2] = Convert.ToByte("11000011", 2);
            sendData[19] = Convert.ToByte("11100111", 2);
            ByteID++;
            if (dataBytesSent == WriteFileSize)
            {
                fileDataSent = true;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Read` reads from the current position in the stream (which is zero upon opening the stream). The second parameter is the offset in the receiving array, not in the stream.

Use [`Seek`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.seek.aspx) to set the current position before reading.

The reading and copying code I would rewrite as:

```
using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(tbFileToSend.Text))
{
    byte[] readBytes = new byte[16];
    fs.Seek(nextReadOffset, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    fs.Read(readBytes, 0, 16);

    readBytes.CopyTo(sendData, 3);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Guys,  Much appreciated.
Does that mean that every time I open the stream:  (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(tbFileToSend.Text);) the file pointer will default to zero?

Also, with the EOF situation where bytes < 16. Will the readBytes[] simply be full of zeros where there was no data to read? Or will I get some kind of error?

Comment: @MichaelAlllen771 As per [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.read.aspx), `Read` returns number of bytes actually read (and therefore actually copied into the destination array), which can be less than number of bytes requested in case there's nothing more. See Remarks section.

Answer (score 0):

The offset in fs.Read() is considered to be the offset in the target array. In your case this sould be always 0. The file pointer increments with every Read() call so you don't have to worry about that. However, you should consider the case when there are not 16 bytes left for reading (return value of Read()).

Comment: Thanks Guys,  Much appreciated.
Does that mean that every time I open the stream:  (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(tbFileToSend.Text);) the file pointer will default to zero?

Also, with the EOF situation where bytes < 16. Will the readBytes[] simply be full of zeros where there was no data to read? Or will I get some kind of error?

Comment: Thank you, You guys on stackoverflow are life savers!

Answer (score 0):

You are reading from a `Stream`, that means once you read something the start point moves to the Postion = Position of last byte you have read + 1.

Next time you read you start from there. You don't need to specify an offset. In fact by doing so you are skipping bytes.

And in your case at some point you are trying to read from a position in the file that does not exist.

So this will do just fine:

```
var numberOfBytesActuallyRead = fs.Read(readBytes, 0, 16);
```

The `numberOfBytesActuallyRead` tells you how many bytes were actually left in the `Stream`. You can then decide how to proceed. The state of the `readBytes` array for values with index > (numberOfBytesActuallyRead -1) is not defined. It might be zeros or your old values.

Comment: Thanks Guys,  Much appreciated.
Does that mean that every time I open the stream:  (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(tbFileToSend.Text);) the file pointer will default to zero?

Also, with the EOF situation where bytes < 16. Will the readBytes[] simply be full of zeros where there was no data to read? Or will I get some kind of error?

Comment: @MichaelAlllen771 Regarding the returned array, the state for the values with an index larger that the bytes actually read is not defined, it might still be your old values or zeros or something totally different

Comment: Thank you, I will put some effort in debugging to verify the contents of returned array. Much Appreciated.

Comment: @MichaelAlllen771 Actually you should not, whatever is returned my changed with any update of the Framework, when something is undefined, it really is undefined and you should not rely on it in any way